# Как скрыть информацию о сайте, с которого пришел

Tags: php, javascript

Есть у меня один сайт. Если я с него по ссылке перехожу на другой сайт, то на том другом сайте можно определить, с какого сайта я пришел.
Как скрыть информацию о своем сайте? Чтобы, когда я перешел со своего сайта на другой, то на этом другом сайте не могли вычислить, с какого сайта пришел я.
Или, если нельзя, скрыть то хоть как подменить информацию?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в секцию `head` строку

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: думаете поможет, если честно это я хочу спрятяться от сайта ВКонтакте. Чтоб не блокирувал мой сайт.

Comment: @Анатолий Почему бы не проверить?

Comment: ну буду пробовать, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

В таких случаях пользуются двойным редиректом или сервисами для сокращения ссылок.